Reflective nebula
I have the beginning of a short story where we follow a marvelous astronomical discovery.
An object 1000 light years away with reflective properties.
Plotpoint: Humanity can use this to see what really happened with jesus.
I started with just a mirror planet and a fat telescope. I realize this is never going to be realistic in any way. Never the less I enjoy muddying the water to make it less silly.
So hence the gigantic nebula cloud with reflective particles was born. Maybe the cloud can be a lens somehow/somewhere and keep the mirror planet?
Is there anything else I could employ to muddy the waters for the science inclined.

The scientifically inclined aren't going to buy into this as being plausible for a moment, there are far too many issues.  (Even ignoring the maximum angular resolution and detectable signal strength at a distance of 1000 ly, stars, planets and nebulae are in motion with respect to each other all the time.  This means that the mirror must be aimed precisely to catch the light from a thousand years ago and reflect it back to where Earth will be a thousand years later.)  Write your story, but the more justification you insert, the more obvious the physics issues will be.

Regardless of the size of your mirror, you won't be able to meaningfully distinguish human figures: atmospheric turbulence restricts resolution to objects in the 5-10 cm range.  This is a hard limit imposed by light scattering through our atmosphere, irrespective of obstacles between us and a reflective nebula.  So "We saw someone giving a speech where the Sermon on the Mount might have happened." is the maximum level of certainty.

Detecting Earth at all would take a minor miracle with any plausibly buildable telescope - and then it would be detected as a shift in the spectral output of Sol, not even its own little speck of light. Fortunately the gospels record an astronomically scaled miracle for your astronomers to try to detect. Assuming a perfect space mirror, a plausibly buildable telescope would be able to identify Sol and measure the sun going dark for a few hours, as recorded in the synoptic gospels.

As to muddying the waters and preserving some scientific credibility: I would highly suggest having scientists be baffled. Scientists are baffled by all kinds of things all the time. You can mention various scientists having pet theories for what the space mirror might be or what it might mean, without ever actually explaining any of those theories. At the bleeding edge of speculative physics you get down to just a few hundred people on the planet who can even follow what any given person is talking about, anyway.

Dr. Ang thinks he can prove that it's a gravitational anomaly resulting from obscure black hole interactions. Dr. Bose thinks Ang is a rigid stick in the mud stuck in 20th century physics, and the real answer will be found once she and her colleagues finally crack loop quantum gravity. Dr. Chen thinks they're both wrong and he can provide an explanation with his 196-dimensional string theory, while Dr. Davidson thinks string theories are should have been abandoned as pseudoscience 40 years ago and suggests that the mirror is best explained as the result of advanced alien mega-engineering...

I try not to vote to close new user questions, so please keep in mind for future posts we are not a brainstorming site. Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum (see [tour]) and open-ended questions that lead to all answers having equal value are prohibited (see [help/dont-ask]). And to head off a question: review-my-idea questions are routinely closed. A better question would have been, "How can I rationalize (tag: [tag:science-fiction]) seeing 2,000 year old light from Earth in a telescope based in Earth orbit." Read [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask]. Thanks.

I agree with @KerrAvon2055: your story probably doesn't need any scientific justification. From what you say, I suspect the story will be focused around personal and/or societial impacts of obtaining a "video" of Jesus. Such stories work especially great if you don't care about the science. Make it (sci)-fi. How humanity got this video is utterly irrelevant to the impact it causes. It could be a wonder, time travel, God himself materializing it on a video tape at your desk, it doesn't matter. Plenty of short stories work this way. Overexplaining science just distracts from the messagge.

Hegemonizing Swarm of Retroreflectors
A self replicating swarm that converts entire planetary systems into a lightyears-wide dispersed cloud of retroreflectors (such as mirror cubes, though some fancy nano-meta-material also sounds plausible) would get around most of the really obvious problems with giant astronomical mirrors and lenses. The cloud would act as a single giant mirror that's always pointed back in your direction, and being lightyears wide might kinda-maybe-plausibly give you the ridiculous resolution you need to see an individual 2000ly away. Created (perhaps unintentionally) by some advanced alien civilization for unknown purposes, but that's besides the point. Would it work in practice? I highly doubt it, but it seems vaguely plausible on cursory inspection, and probably about the best you'll do.

Interstellar objects with a high enough mass can bend light. Nasa Scientific Visualization Studio shows how our own sun bends light from other stars.
Though there are clearly some issues with using telescopes to see back in our own history on Earth, as pointed out by user KerrAvon2055, one could say that this nebula (or black hole, as they are commonly far more popularly known for "muddy waters physics") bent the light back towards earth.

Based on the tags, I understand this is a hard-science question regarding "seeing into the past" using strictly astronomical methods. We shall assume the mirror is large enough and "flat" enough to prevent any distortions of the image. Here are few points to consider:
1- Location of the mirror: The farther away an object is, the more we see it into the past, because light takes that amount of time to reach our eyes, so the image we see is older than its current image. If you want to look into the past, roughly 2000 years ago, the mirror must be 1000 light-years away. It takes light from Earth (showing Jesus) 1000 years to reach the mirrors, and 1000 more years to reach us after it bounces back. If the mirror is closer to us, we may have missed that period. If it is farther away, we will have to wait longer.
2- Image quality: I don't think a nebula can behave as a mirror. A planet with a surface "polished" by some alien civilization may do. However, the mirror may be spherical, so light bouncing off of the planet will diverge more quickly as it heads back to us. The image will also appear smaller and astronomers will have to work harder to increase its resolution. Happily, the planet is big enough to retrieve a high-resolution picture. Using a flat mirror is problematic. Any object massive enough will collapse under its own gravity. So maybe a rotating disk held up by balancing gravity and centrifugal force may work. A mirror array will be possible. Maybe they orbit the planet and give it a set of rings.
3- Using a lens: A gigantic lens will be impractical. Glass becomes opaque beyond few feet of thickness. Something that does not obstruct the light can serve as a lens: Dark matter. Use gravitational lensing instead of a classical lens. The aliens can gather dark matter and put it into orbit to increase the power of their "telescope". The celestial objects are difficult to keep aligned if they are too close. They may be actively stabilized to aim the telescope, or maybe quite by chance a distant lump of dark matter between Earth and the mirror sits just right.
